# Equivalence of Ising and Random Cluster Model Partition Functions

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, statistical-mechanics

It is well documented that the partition function of the Ising model is equivalent to the partition function of the Random Cluster model. However I cannot seem to find a resource that actually shows this. To be specific, let $G=(V,E)$ be some graph and $$Z_I = \Sigma_{\sigma: V\rightarrow \{-1,1\}}e^{-\beta H(\sigma)},\: H(\sigma) = -J\Sigma_{xy\in E} \sigma(x)\sigma(y),$$
where $\beta, J \in [0,\infty)$ and
$$Z_{RC} = \Sigma_{\omega:E \rightarrow \{0,1\}}(\Pi_{e\in E}p^{\omega(e)}(1-p)^{1-\omega(e)})q^{k(\omega)},$$
where $p\in[0,1],q\in (0,\infty)$ and $k(\omega)$ is the number of connected components of the graph $(V,\{e\in E: \omega(e) = 1\})$ . Then how would one go about showing that $Z_{I} = Z_{RC}$ for some suitable constants? Also, direction towards any resources properly showing this would be appreciated too.

Comment: You can find the proof in as Proposition 3.3 in ”Graphical representations of lattice spin model” lecture notes by Hugo Duminil-Copin. You can find the link in the author's webpage: https://www.unige.ch/~duminil/publi/2016Peccot.pdf

Comment: Notice that the Potts model with $q=2$ is equivalent to the Ising model.

Comment: @Kernel Thanks a lot, I had a look but I am confused about the jump from the second to third equality in Remark 3.5?

Comment: There is also a (slightly more detailed) derivation in Section 3.10.6 of [our book](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook). You can also find a (more complicated) derivation in the original paper by Fortuin and Kasteleyn, for instance.